# Bootstrap 3 Collapse div button just jumping not opening

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on this site http://hellonextstep.com/Clients/ONS/why-reviews.php

The see more reviews button is supposed to open the `#collapse-review` section.

I'm calling bootstrap js on just this one page via

```
<a class="review-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-review">See More Reviews +</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript console has your answer:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
>   or higher

Include the correct jQuery version and it should work - the above error message is coming up because you're linking to 1.7.1

Comment: Ahh, well then. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: additional question you might be able to help me with. The section is loading open, when I need it to open closed. Then when collapsed the section is visible below the top layer. Thoughts?

Comment: @MattSornson: Please start a new question. It's hard to help through comments. Others also may be able to help more than I can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Jquery 1.11.1

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
```